# How to make modal close after validation using Vue js?

Tags: modal-dialog, vuejs2, quasar

I am using `<q-modal>`(Quasar Framework) for a form. On clicking `Add` button a form will pop over. In this, I am validating each form tags, after clicking submit button. To close the modal, I am using `@click="$refs.maximizedModal.close()"` for submit button.

Everything works fine. Now I need to retain modal if the validation is not returning true or if validation satisfies then the modal need to be closed.

Is there any method to do conditional submit in Vue js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a custom function for the submit of the form and use it, something like this :

....

```
methods{
  checkForm(e){
    if(VALIDATION_IS_TRUE){
      //Validation has passed, we submit the form OR close the modal
      $refs.maximizedModal.close(); // Maybe this.$refs.maximizedModal.close()
      e.target.submit();
    }else{
       //The form is not validated, do something to inform the user
    }
  }
}
```

and instead of using the @click for the submit button, add this to the form element :

```
<form @submit.prevent='checkForm($event)'>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both $refs.maximizedModal.close() and this.$refs.maximizedModal.close() are getting error. The error is -  this.$refs.maximizedModal  is not a function.

Comment: If "this.$refs.maximizedModal.close()" is not a function, then perhaps you are not accessing the maximizedModal object properly. In this case, you should have a component inside the current one, something like this <some-tag ref='maximizedModal'></some-tag>. If such tag is not found, an error like yours will occure. If the maximized modal is not a child of that component you will not be able to access it that way. Keep in mind that @click="$refs.maximizedModal.close()" is the same as defining "this.$refs.maximizedModal.close()" inside a method in your vuejs component.